# Google Sheets App Script Distance Calculator Enhanced functionality

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to add more functionality to a Google Sheets script to

1. Loop through a column of zip codes
2. See if they are blank
3. Loop through a column of distances
4. See if they are blank
5. If the zip code cell of a row is NOT blank, && the distance cell Is blank then call a function the find the distance between the 2 addresses.
6. Insert the value of the distance found into the blank cell of that row.

Here is my code; it is throwing an error stating I'm missing a ")" on 3rd line, but I'm not sure why. Please help!

```
`function autoDistance(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var zipValue = sheet.getRange(W2:W);
var distanceCell = sheet.getRange(Y2:Y);

for (var i=1;i<zipValue.length;i++){
  var emptyShipZip = isBlank(zipValue[i][22]);
  var emptyDistVal = isBlank(distanceCell[i][24])
  if(emptyShipZip==false && emptyDistVal==true){
    var finalDist = drivingDistance(zipValue[i][22].value,"12517 NE 91st Avenue Okeechobee, FL 34972");
  return distanceCell[i][24].setValue(finalDist);
}
else{
    break;       
} 

}`
```

Comment: It's not valid JavaScript. You need to put the range in quotes: `sheet.getRange("W2:W")`

Comment: Also, after calling getRange(...), a call to getValues() is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
function autoDistance() {
    //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<<spreadsheet id>>").getSheetByName("<<Sheet1>>");
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var sheetValues = sheet.getRange(2, 23, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < sheetValues.length; i++) {
        var shipZip = sheetValues[i][0];
        var distVal = sheetValues[i][1];
        if (shipZip != "" && distVal == "") {
            var finalDist = drivingDistance(shipZip, "12517 NE 91st Avenue Okeechobee, FL 34972");
            sheet.getRange(i + 2, 24, 1, 1).setValue(finalDist);
        }
    }
}
```